# Matching paths to exclude from mv moving with bash globbing

Tags: bash, wildcards, mv

I'm editing an install script to exclude a few directories from being installed, under the base directory, as they're already on the system, and I'll save about a gig doing this. I keep getting `mv: target '/tmp/makepkg/unreal-engine/pkg/unreal-engine/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Binaries'` is not a directory
I've tried escaping `/` with `\` with no luck. Also tried various other means of using `mvmod` What's off in my script?

```
shopt -s extglob # at the very top above all variables in actual script. Not in the function
local mvmod
if [ -n "_system_mono" ];
then
  thirdparty="Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty"
  mvmod="!($thirdparty/Mono|$thirdparty/Python|$thirdparty/Python3)"    
else
  mvmod=" " 
fi

mv Engine/Binaries "${mvmod}" "$path_to_Folder/Engine/Binaries"
```

`path_to_folder` starts from where `Engine` is located. If I leave `mvmod` as just a space character everything moves properly. All of the files are definitely there.

Comment: when moving multiple files with the `mv`  command the last argument to the `mv` command must be a directory that you should tell it by the `-t` switch like `mv file1 file2 file3 .... fileN -t /path/to/some/directory`; also in `-n "_system_mono"` you meant `-n "$_system_mono"`? see also https://shellcheck.net to verify your script online

Comment: Ah, stackoverflow has an answer that makes it seem unnecessary. Need to check shellcheck on my machine. It should be catching those typos.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612157/how-to-use-mv-command-to-move-files-except-those-in-a-specific-directory

Comment: Starting the install over. I tried testing it, while running the packaging command again, and it still gave the same error.

Comment: Files are definitely there.

Comment: Your (extended) glob never gets expanded since it is quoted - you probably want to declare `mvmod` as an array and assign either `mvmod=( !($thirdparty/Mono|$thirdparty/Python|$thirdparty/Python3) )` or `mvmod=()` and then expand it in the `mv` command as `"${mvmod[@]}"`

Comment: It seems to me that the actual problem is that you bundled system or packaged libraries under your app's directory.   The actual solution is "don't do that", not "figure out how to not to move files/dirs that shouldn't be there in the first place".

Comment: @cas Those are already there. I'm removing files Unreal includes by default.